# Django-Templated-Email: TemplateDoesNotExist when importing from a different file

Tags: python, django, email

I have a Django project with two apps: email_app and landing_page_app.  The `landing_page_app.views` includes `email_app.views`, so that it can use the `new_lead_email` function.

In `email_app.views`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from templated_email import send_templated_mail

def new_lead_email(email):
    send_templated_mail(
        template_name='new_lead',
        from_email='name@somewhere.com',
        recipient_list=['name@somewhere.com'],
        context={
            'email': email,
            'current_time': str(datetime.now()),
            },
    )
```

In `landing_page_app.views`:

```
from email_app.views import new_lead_email
new_lead_email(email)
```

I get a "TemplateDoesNotExist" error for "templated_email/new_lead.txt".  The `new_lead_email` function works correctly when it is not imported into `landing_page_app.views` (i.e. if I have a Django URL call `new_lead_email` in `email_app.views` directly).

In settings.py, I set `TEMPLATED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DIR` and `TEMPLATED_EMAIL_FILE_EXTENSION` to a directory that contains the "new_lead.email" template. This suggests that the vanilla_django.py file in django-templated-email (https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email/blob/master/templated_email/backends/vanilla_django.py) is not importing my settings.py file correctly.

Do you have any suggestions for how to import functions in `email_app.views` into other files and have the templates work correctly.  Thanks to bradwhittington for a VERY useful Django class.  I look forward to learning how to use it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be importing views from one app into views from another. Try creating a utils.py for email_app and putting your function in there. I am currently doing this for a generic email sending function for a project, using a globalutils.py file in project root. It sends txt/html emails from templates I have in templates/email/, also in project root.

Here are the first few lines of the method

```
def send_message(template_name, subject_context, body_context, recipients, sender=None, send_email=True, send_internal=True):

subject = render_to_string("%s/%s_%s.%s" % ("email", template_name, "subject", "txt"), subject_context)
t_html = render_to_string("%s/%s_%s.%s" % ("email", template_name, "body", "html"), body_context)
t_text = strip_tags(t_html)
```

This will send email no matter which apps call it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I switched to a common file for these kinds of functions.  I am still having the same problem that the `send_templated_mail` function isn't correctly "reading" the settings.py file to know where to look for email templates.

Comment: Are you doing include settings.py in your common file and os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'email template dir')?